# How long did the Mercury astronauts have to stay in the isolation tank?

Tags: project-mercury, astronaut-recruitment

Among the many things Mercury astronaut candidates had to go through, they had to go through a sensory deprivation experiment and spend some time in a sensory isolation tank. How long did they have to stay in the isolation tank to qualify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three hours, according to [*Space Medicine in Project Mercury*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19650022793), p. 55:

> 7. Isolation: Subject goes into a dark, soundproof room for **3
>    hours** to determine his ability to adapt to unusual circumstances
>    and to cope with the absence of external stimuli.

There's a picture of Deke Slayton taking the test on p. 56.  It's a chair in a dark room; there's no tank.

Comment: It's kind of hard to see what's going on in that picture!